# freeradius + daloradius возврат атрибутов профиля

Tags: freeradius

установлен и настроен freeradius сервер с daloradius, в базе созданы тестовые пользователи user и operator. Создан профиль для оператора Operators с атрибутом Group.
Но при тестовой авторизации freeradius не возвращает атрибут Group для пользователя operator.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?